# Octo.py only using between 0% and 3% of my CPUs

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I have been running a Python octo.py script to do word counting/author on a series of files. The script works well -- I tried it on a limited set of data and am getting the correct results.

But when I run it on the complete data set it takes forever. I am running on a windows XP laptop with dual core 2.33 GHz and 2 GB RAM.

I opened up my CPU usage and it shows the processors running at 0%-3% of maximum.

What can I do to force Octo.py to utilize more CPU?

Thanks.

Comment: Most probably your OS is swapping or your program is hitting the HDD as the bottleneck. This is often the case with systems with a low amount of RAM and/or slow HDDs such as 5200 RPM laptop hard drives. Can you check if the HDD LED is constantly on?

Comment: Yes, it's constantly on! But other programs like Mathematica seem to be able to suck up large % of the CPUs.

Comment: Different programs are limited by different components. If your script processed data with a small amount of CPU cycles, it requires quick disk I/O. Other programs might stress mostly the CPU, in which case they will load the CPU a lot, but not the hard drive. It's a mirror problem.

Comment: That's probably it! Unfortunately I can't accept your response because it's showing up as a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your application isn't very CPU intensive, the slow disk turns out to be the bottleneck. Old 5200 RPM laptop hard drives are very slow, which, in addition to fragmentation and low RAM (which impacts disk caching), make reading very slow. This in turns slows down processing and yields low CPU usage. You can try defragmenting, compressing the input files (as they become smaller in disk size, processing speed will increase) or other means of improving IO.